# Installshield doesn't show default language

Tags: installshield

I have a question of installation language of Installshield.

I built a installation project support 3 languages Korean, English and Japanese. and the Default Language is English Of Course.

when my product installed on Korean language Windows, It shows Korean. it's good. 
when installing on English Windows it shows English. it's good too.

But problem is a langpack on Windows.

E.g. Korean Language Windows + Chinese Language Pack.
and the User set the default windows language as Chinese.

in this case, I expect English on installation. because Default language of my install project is "English". But It shows "Korean".

anyone knows about this?
is this a bug? or a policy of Flexera?

My installshield is 2013 Premier Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Per my [old answer in another forum](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?179399-Why-Default-Language-can-t-work&p=412574#post412574), the term "default" is misleading. Instead this setting lets you select the fallback when there does not appear to be a better mach. In the case you describe, the Korean language of the machine is matching with the Korean available in the installation, so the "default" has no effect.